# CakePHP handling multiple Clients

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to create a website that will have the following

1. Web Access
2. Android/iPhone Mobile app accessing API
3. Mobile Web

I want all the above three to access the same webroot and resources in terms of Images.
the URL will be

1. site.com
2. api.site.com
3. m.site.com

may be an alternative touchscreen site at touch.site.com

How can I have CakePHP handle all these in one installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing to do is to use [prefixes](http://book.cakephp.org/view/950/Prefix-Routing). Internally your URLs will be routed like `/api/controller/action` to an action called `api_action`. You can switch layouts/authentication/whatever logic in your beforeFilters depending on the prefix (`$this->params['prefix']`).

For handling this as subdomains you just have to do some internal .htaccess rewriting to change URLs from `api.example.com/` to your `example.com/api` prefix. To properly reverse-route links, you're probably best off implementing a custom [RouteClass](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1634/Custom-Route-classes). Look at the default [CakeRoute](http://api13.cakephp.org/view_source/cake-route/#l-1236) class for guidance.